# Assembler registers calculation

Tags: assembly, ram, nand2tetris

I have problem with i guess simple example in assembler:

```
 RAM[0] :=RAM[1]%2
```

I don´t know how to calculate this. Please Could you help me ?

We use A and C instructions. And sytax is probably Intel

Comment: Please edit your question specifying which machine architecture you're dealing with. The assembly is different for each architecture.

Comment: By Intel syntax, are you implying you are dealing with x86? Then is it 64-bit, 32-bit, or 16-bit? Also, there is no `A` and `C` instruction in x86 or in any CPU produced by Intel, AFAIK.

Comment: it's about nand2tetris chapter 4 i think. So x86 and 16 bit I think

Comment: If you're dealing with 16-bit x86, place the appropriate tags, probably `x86` and `8086`. But apart from that, saying again, there is no instruction named `A` or `C` in x86 or in any CPU produced by Intel.

Comment: I meant command instructions and address instructions, okey

Comment: Just name the instruction you are talking about from here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings#Original_8086/8088_instructions)

Comment: Read RAM[1] first, then calculate %2, then write the result to RAM[0]. Does that help?

Comment: smthing like this ? : 
@1
D=M
D=D%A
@0
D=M
M=D

Comment: Syntax is not Intel, but Nand2Tetris Hack

Comment: The Hack Machine Language is not any x86 nor intel.  It comes from Nand2tetris project, which examines a simple computer from a very low level / mostly hardware perspective. 
 https://zhongchuyun.gitbooks.io/nand2tetris/content/chapter_4.html

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
RAM[0] := RAM[1] % 2
```

has a read of RAM[1] and a write of RAM[0].

Your proposal:

```
@1
D=M               **1st**
D=D%A
@0
D=M               **2nd**
M=D
```

has two problems it. It reflects

```
D = RAM[1] % 2
RAM[0] := RAM[0]
```

Can you see that the 2nd D=M doesn't belong, because (1) there is no read of RAM[0] in the original expression, and that (2) doing the 2nd D=M wipes out the %2 result that was previously in `D`?  That 2nd D=M line should simply be deleted.

---

However, there's one more problem: the Hack computer cannot express a modulus, `%`, operation.

But, the divisor for the modulus for this expression is a constant, which happens to be a power of 2, and those can be computed with masking, using the logical operator `&` as long as the input is unsigned or positive<sup>1</sup>.

The appropriate mask for modulus by some power of 2, P, here 2, and where N= Log<sub>2</sub>(P) = Log<sub>2</sub>(2) = 1 is given by the formula 2<sup>N</sup>-1 = 2<sup>1</sup>-1 = 2-1, and so is simply 1.

So, we transform the expression into the following equivalent:

```
RAM[0] := RAM[1] & 1
```

And convert similar to what you did above.  Note that there are only two `&` operations on hack, one is D&A and the other is D&M.

```
@1         # load A with value 1 (to be used as address)
D=M        # Read RAM[1] into D

@1         # this line is technically unnecessary since A already holds 1
           # but it would be necessary in RAM[0] := RAM[2] & 1
D=D&A      # mask D with A going back to D

@0         # load A with value 0
M=D        # store D in RAM[0]
```

---

<sup>1</sup>  For signed numbers that are negative it is more complicated because the mask operation makes the result either 0 or +1, whereas %2 will do either 0 or -1 respectively.  (So, when the input is negative the mask result would have to be negated to equal the %2 result.)

Comment: Regarding the footnote: It is more complicated for *signed* numbers, isn't it?

Comment: @Sebastian Yes, thanks!